# safari issue - navbar brand pushes down toggleable navbar

Tags: html, safari, mobile-safari, navbar, bootstrap-4

This is only an issue I'm having in Safari. In chrome and firefox, my navbar brand and collapsable nav line up on the same line in mobile.

In safari, in mobile view, the collapsable nav is pushed down the page, out of line with the brand. This only happens when the nav is collapsed.

Above the small breakpoint, the nav is a normal menu, links spread out horizontally, and they line up with the brand properly, in safari, firefox, and chrome.

What can I do to fix this? I have already tried applying a float left to the collapse div, which I saw as a solution in a similar post, but it didn't work. 
How can I set it so the logo within the nav-brand is the ONLY clickable part instead of the entire top part of the screen being a link?

It seems like the brand is displaying too wide, as it makes the entire top of the screen into a link instead of just the brand logo image. This happens in chrome too but it doesn't cause the toggle to be pushed down.

Edit: I set a max-width for the navbar-brand link. This stopped the entire top of the page from being that link but the toggleable navbar is still being pushed down in safari. 
I also have a margin-left applied to the UL above 768px but I take this away from the UL outside the breakpoints. 
[This is what's happening. It happens with the navbar toggle collapsed and expanded.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Njtxm.png)

You can see the issue in this bootply: https://www.bootply.com/qlBBAGHYvU
(I changed the colors of the navbar text to show up but can't figure out why the toggle navigation isn't visible, but it's located just to the left of the right side of the viewport, and just under the black navbar bar.)

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-inverse fixed-top">

    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#page-top" style="max-width:20%;"><img class="img-fluid" src="backgroundimages/logoSmall.png"></a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item navMenuBox">
        <a class="nav-link navmenu" style="display:block;" href="#howto">How to Use</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item navMenuBox">
        <a class="nav-link navmenu" style="display:block;" href="#Mappy">Map</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item navMenuBox">
        <a class="nav-link navmenu" style="display:block;" href="#about">About</a>
      </li>
        <li class="nav-item navMenuBox">
        <a class="nav-link navmenu" style="display:block;" href="#contact">Contact</a>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

relevant css:

```
    ul {
width:100%;
background-color: #611B81;
}

    li {
padding-left: 2%;
text-align: center;
    }

    li:hover {
background-color: #7E157D;
    }

            /* styles nav items & adds hover effects*/

    @media (max-width: 575px) {
    .navmenu {
        border: 0px;
        padding-right: 20%;
        display: table;
        text-align: center;
        color: #fff;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        display: inline-block;
        font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
    }
        }

    @media (min-width: 768px) {
       .navMenuBox {
        margin-right: 5%;
    } 
        .navmenu {
        border: 2px solid #fff;
        padding-right: 20%;
        display: table;
        text-align: center;
        color: #fff;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        display: inline-block;
        font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;

    }

     .navmenu:link {
        outline: 2px solid #fff; 
        border: 4px solid transparent;
       padding-right: 20%;
        display: table;
        text-align: center;
        color: #fff;
    }

    .navmenu:visited {
        outline: 2px solid #fff;
        border: 4px solid transparent;
        display: table;
        text-align: center;
        color: #fff;
    }

    .navmenu:hover {
        outline: 2px solid #fff;
        border: 4px solid #fff;
        display: table;
        text-align: center;
        color: #fff;
    }

    .navmenu:active {
        outline: 2px solid #fff;
        border: 4px solid #fff;
        display: table;
        text-align: center;
        color: #fff; 

    } 

    }
```

Comment: How can we help w/o seeing the code?

Comment: @ZimSystem sorry I'd figured it was a fairly general issue with a general fix but I've added my code